# Cakephp pagination first page page:1

Tags: cakephp, pagination

In Cakephp 1 the first page of pagination also put page:1 in the url, how do I get CakePHP 2 to also do that? I know I read it somewhere, but I can't seem to find that page with a solution.

I know it was a visual/design solution from CakePHP self, but I need that page:1 part.

I hope someone can help me...

Comment: this is working very well in cakephp2.x. I assume the reason you think is not working because the first time loading page:1 is inactive. but if you click in other pages and click in page:1 you see it works well :)

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: I'm sorry, I will add my CakePHP version in my future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We removed the page:1 part in CakePHP2.4 as it served no real purpose and made it SEO-invalid (both / and /page:1 accessed the same page).
See the [migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-4-migration-guide.html#paginatorhelper)

My tip: 301 redirect (via htaccess or some custom component) the old to the new URL. 
Than

- you wont need it
- it's all SEO friendly (no juice lost)
- it's future proof

Simple CakePHP implementation could be:

- if named param action page == 1
- then redirect(new url, 301) with new url = old url without named param page

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try to get this to work. For now I will use 472084's answer, because it's an Ajax Pagination and his answer works. But we still have to look into making it as SEO friendly as we can, so I will definitely try out what you suggested!

Comment: Since CakePHP 2.0+ it is also highly recommended to not use named params anymore, but query strings, see http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params/